# Why in this sentence has an article "the"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Sentence:
"You've got to **the** count of five to let me out of here." (it's from futurama first episode.).

Why in this sentence is definite-article?
Is "count" a noun in this sentence?

Comment: It's an idiomatically established usage where dissecting the actual "grammar" won't necessarily help you much, but I'd guess "count" here refers to *any* number within the sequence the speaker is about to enumerate. Where ***the** count* refers specifically to [speaking out loud] the value "five" - when speaker reaches that number, the specified condition has been reached, so the addressee must release the speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You've got to the count of five to let me out of here."

**Q. Why in this sentence is definite-article?**

---

A. **By using the definite-article the**, we’ve shown that it was one **specific count** that we are relating too.

> **Articles are words that define a noun as specific or unspecific**. Consider the following example:

> **After the long day, the cup of tea tasted particularly good.**

> **By using the article the**, we’ve shown that it was **one specific day** that was long and one specific cup of tea that tasted good.

> **After a long day, a cup of tea tastes particularly good.**

> By using the **article a, we’ve created a general statement**, implying that any cup of tea would taste good after any long day.

Ref [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles/)

Comment: And one more little question. Is "count" a noun in this sentence?

Comment: @JustOneMan  Yes, *count* is a noun here.  It must be a noun, because it has an article, and only nouns take articles.

Comment: But there are some rare cases: "All the more", "the better", and that's why I doubt about article always only with nouns.

Comment: better is an adjective ; adverb or noun depending on its use https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/better?q=+better   More is a 
determiner, pronoun, adverb